# How to get User Default parameters?

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm implementing custom SAP Fiori application with Create functionality. Three of the input fields are SD-related organizational data. I would like to set that inputs based on User Default values from Fiori Launchpad settings.

I know, that this kind of parameters needs to be added into Target mapping in Launchpad Designer using syntax below:

for single-value parameters

```
%%UserDefault.<parameterName>%%
```

for sets of values and value ranges

```
%%UserDefault.extended.<parameterName>%%
```

but when navigating into the application that values are not added into URI.

How and where (onInit?) can I read that values? Is it necessary to call another oData service to read defaults or I'm able to do that using navigation parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You can check in the init method of your Component.js via `this.getComponentData( ).startupParameters`. They should be available there, if you have set them via the "Me Area" before.